# Azure DevOps Build Best Practices for Multiple YMLS

Tags: azure-devops

I have a question on general best practices for Azure DevOps. When building a project, we have two build configs, debug or release. At some point in the deployment pipeline across a multi-stage environments, these need to be changed, which means two builds from what I can understand.

Is it better to have one yml, with the build config being set as a condition from the source branch (i.e. if source branch contains "release" build config is Release, if source branch isn't from release, then config is Debug, or should I be having multiple builds and a pipeline triggered by two different artifacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much better to have one yml. By having only the one build pipeline and using a simple condition, you limit the possibility of bugs arising due to differences in the separate yml definitions. Additionally, it is more maintainable as changes are only made in one place.

Comment: That's what I feel like. 1 YML with a bit more complex definition, and release that one build across multiple envs.

Comment: I'd agree, with the qualification that your scenario calls for a single *pipeline*, which could include reusable job/stage/variable components in templates - in that scenario, you would have multiple YAML files, but that would be a good thing.